# How do I hide the Jest types so I can use Mocha?

Tags: typescript, mocha.js

**Question:**

How do I get the Jest types to not come up automatically? They're creating a false positive for me since I'm actually running the unit tests with Mocha.

**Context:**

I'm looking to use TSDX but to run the tests in the browser. Unfortunately, TSDX comes pre-installed with Jest which doesn't test in a browser. So that makes Mocha the correct choice for a unit testing library (since it has high popularity and runs in a browser).

Answer (score 1):

create a file called `weDoNotUseJest.d.ts` in `src`

The content of this file should be:

```
declare const expect: "If you're seeing this type, that means you forgot to import expect from Chai. We're not using Jest";

declare const describe: "If you're seeing this type, that means you forgot to place `import 'mocha'` above your test. We're not using Jest";

declare const test: "If you're seeing this type, that means you forgot to place `import 'mocha'` above your test. We're not using Jest";
```

Now, when any developer creates a new test, the IDE (i.e. VSCode) will provide an error message that is more clear. For instance, given the following code:

```
import { sum } from '.';
import { expect } from 'chai';

describe('blah', () => {
  test('works', () => {
    expect(sum(1, 1)).eq(2);
  });
});
```

... you'll actually see an error message and it will be pretty helpful:

`const describe: "If you're seeing this type, that means you forgot to place` import 'mocha' `above your test. We're not using Jest" This expression is not callable. Type 'String' has no call signatures.ts(2349)`

Comment: `TS2451: Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'expect'.` complains about existing Jest declaration in `node_modules@types/jest/index.d.ts`